# Regex: Only matching at the end of String not anywhere in elastic

Tags: regex

I would like to find and match a pattern of character "ab" with any number. I've been trying

```
.*([0-9]+ab)
```

this seems to work but is only finding any matches at the end of a string, not in any location of the string.

testString = "if this was a test string 123ab"

TestStringNotFound = "if this 123ab string was a test"

however by using

```
.*([0-9]+ab).*
```

it seems to look at any location of the string but from my understanding
`.` is just referring to any character and `*` was any digit. So I'm struggling to understand why adding `.*` to the end will return the specified match anywhere in the string.

I've been using this [documentation](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/editors/ne/Regular_Expressions.html) as a guide gave me the impression that `([0-9]+ab)` would be the way to write this expression. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `*` is a quantifyer (not a digit), meaning: the preceding character or group of characters zero or more times.

Comment: Both strings can be found.  Play with the regex in regex101.com: https://regex101.com/r/kwHEGL/2

Comment: Why you're putting wildcards at the both ends?   /(\d+ab)/g - finds every occurrences!

Comment: @h-sifat perhaps because [the regular expression must match the entire string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html) ?

Comment: `.` matches any char but a line feed char. `*` means "zero or more, as many times as possible", so `.*` matches any text on the line.